# XElement iteration won't work

Tags: c#, xml, ienumerable, xelement

I am trying to go through this XML:

```
<result>
    <diaryelement>
       <diary_uid>86248040</diary_uid>
       <diary_date>1347274789</diary_date>
       <diary_type>0</diary_type>

       <diaryshortitem>
         <itemid>419</itemid>
         <data>...</data>
          <description>...</description>
       </diaryshortitem>
    </diaryelement>
</result>
```

and the code I am using for iteration is:

```
XElement diary = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
IEnumerable<XElement> diaryelements = diary.Descendants("result");

Debug.WriteLine("No error");

                foreach (XElement diaryelement in diaryelements) 
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(diaryelement.Value);
                    Debug.WriteLine((string)diaryelement.Element("diaryelement").Element("diaryshortitem").Element("description").Element("data").Value);
                }

Debug.WriteLine("Loop ended");
```

But the method seems to skip the iteration and I don't know why.

Comment: "result" is not a descendant.  Try diary.DescendantsAndSelf.  You will get errors inside the loop but that will get you into the loop so you can go from there.

Comment: I get a nullpointer when I try it with DescendantsAndSelf. Even when I start from Element("result") in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<XElement> diaryelements = diary.Descendants("diaryelement");
```

This change gets all the Descendants of "diaryelement" after this you can parse one by one

Comment: You are the man, pal! It would be nice though, if you could tell me why my first implementation did not work.

Comment: Its like your 1st node is "result" pointer is already there now you next get is Descendants of "diaryelement" not the "result".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `XElement.Parse` try to use `XDocument.Parse`. Also, consider adjusting xml elements path
on this line

```
Debug.WriteLine((string)diaryelement.Element("diaryelement").Element("diaryshortitem").Element("description").Element("data").Value);
```

as it is not correct.

Comment: Do you mean the missing .Element("name") ?

Comment: I mean that `Element("description")` in your xml doesn't contain children